# How can I have it so images don't flicker when ajax is called?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, live

On this page: http://friendsconnect.org/chat/ you can see a very simple chat. How can I have it so the image doesn't flicker each time ajax is called?

Javascript:

```
function execute_check(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'chat.php',
        success: function(data){
            $("#container").html(data);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(execute_check, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont send the image and update only content.

Comment: Sample page was down so I couldn't check, but this makes sense to me, too. If you are indeed sending the image, there's no need.

Comment: @gregp Apologies, my friend. For some reason the page was down, try it again.